# double NAT virtual box DNS issues

Tags: dns

This is driving my crazy. I have two VM's runnig in Virtual Box , Windows 7 and vyos. Windows 7 and the inside LAN interface of vyos VM share the 10.0.0.0/8 address space. The outside interface of vyos is configured to get it's IP via DHCP (in Virtual Box it's set to Bridge Mode) hence it receives an IP from the range of 192.168.0.0/24 (this is the address space assigned by my ISP's router - the box with arrows). I've configured PAT on vyos so that everything from 10.0.0.0 will be translate to whatever is on vyos outside interface. Ping works just fine, no problems to ping 8.8.8.8 or any other service on the Internet, the problem however is DNS! it's no working at ALL. what should I set for the DNS on the Windows 7 VM in the NIC configuration ? I have also configured DNS forwarding so that vyos listens on the inside interface for DNS queries and sends them to the DNS server that my ISP is assigning to my physical laptop, but no go, still failing that it cannot resolve the name.

[image]
Any ideas ?

Comment: Why not just hardcode 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4  (Googles nameservers) and be done with it?

Comment: @davidgo you mean in the Windows 7 VM ? Tried that as well, still not working.